How can I programmatically emit update:modelValue of a wrapped Vuetify component?
I created following component:
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{
  langs: string[]
}>()
</script>

<template>
  <v-btn-toggle>
    <v-btn
      v-for="lang in langs"
      :key="lang"
      :text="$t(`languages.${lang}`)"
      :value="lang"
    ></v-btn>
  </v-btn-toggle>
</template>

And I'm using it like this:
<LangBtnToggle
  v-model="selectedLang"
  :langs
/>

Thanks to fallthrough attributes mechanism $attrs is bound to v-btn-toggle and everythig works as expected.
Now I want to change LangBtnToggle code so that as soon as it receives the langs it emits the first one as default value, like this:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { watchEffect } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps<{
  langs: string[]
}>()

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

watchEffect(() => {
  emit('update:modelValue', props.langs[0])
})
</script>

<template>
  <v-btn-toggle>
    <v-btn
      v-for="lang in langs"
      :key="lang"
      :text="$t(`languages.${lang}`)"
      :value="lang"
    ></v-btn>
  </v-btn-toggle>
</template>

Now selectedLang receives the default value and everything seems to work, but when I click on the other langs from the UI it doesn't update.
Maybe this is not the proper way to do it, do you know how can I achieve my goal?

Your component shouldn't emit anything on render - you already know from outside of it which is the default value.

@moonwave99 You are right, but the default value is not always the first element, it's calculated (I simplified the example to make the question easier). Therefore I wanted to incorporate the calculation logic in the component. Do you think it's a bad idea?

Since the UI component takes no part in the decision, I'd say yes.

@moonwave99 when you say "the UI component takes no part in the decision", wdym? Can you expand on it?


don't use watchEffect. That's an ugly React thing, that should be avoided at all costs. Vue has smart and intuitive ways to solve problems.

Solution

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

const { t } = useI18n();

const props = defineProps<{
  langs: string[];
}>()

const lang = ref<string>('');

onMounted(() => {
  lang.value = props.langs.lengs ? props.langs[0] : '';
});
</script>

<template>
  <v-btn-toggle v-model="lang">
    <v-btn
      v-for="lang in props.langs"
      :key="lang"
      :value="lang"
    >{{ t(`languages.${lang}`) }}</v-btn>
  </v-btn-toggle>
</template>


I don't like using an internal v-model, since this is a component where you can use v-model directly on it (like text fields).
